# sql query not returning non-unique value in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database for an investor to track his investments:

- the 'deal' table has info about the investments, including different categories for the investment (asset_class).
- Another table ('updates') tracks updates on a specific investment (investment name, date, and lots of financial details.)

I want to write a query that allows the user to select all updates from 'updates' under a specific asset_class.  However, as mentioned, asset_class is in the investment table.  I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM updates
WHERE updates.invest_name IN (SELECT deal.deal_name
                              FROM deal
                              WHERE deal.asset_class = '$asset_class'
                             );
```

I'm using PHP, so `$asset_class` is the selected variable of asset_class.
However, the query only returns unique update names, but I want to see ALL updates for the given asset_class, even if several updates are made under one investment name.
Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Your query is doing what you intend.  If you have a problem with the results, it might lie in the PHP code.

Comment: You can add sample data/desired results (or ask another question with this information).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should do what you intend.  In general, though, this type of query would be written using a `JOIN`.  More importantly use parameter placeholders instead of munging query strings:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM updates u JOIN
     deal d
     ON u.invest_name = d.deal_name
WHERE d.asset_class = ?;
```

This can take advantage of indexes on `deal(asset_class, deal_name)` and `updates(invest_name)`.

The `?` represents a parameter that you pass into the query when you run it.  The exact syntax depends on how you are making the call.

Comment: Hi, I tried both of them in the MySQL console, but I'm still not getting all of the results from the updates table.  I took a screenshot, but I don't see have to attach it here.  Thanks!